# Installed April CU, but build version did not change

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, cumulative-update

I had to install the re-released sp1 first and then I was able to run the April CU update. When it was finished I restarted the server and ran config wizard. My build version is still `15.04701.100` instead of `​15.0.4711.1000`. Have I missed a step?

Comment: Did you run the config wizard on all the servers in the farm? As you described, you have to install the re-released version of SP1 first and then install the CU for April 2015.. seems like there is more to it. Do you have any language packs installed? http://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=565

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you mentioned, you install the SP1 and then install the April CU. But the build number you mentioned is for March CU.So couple of things to make sure.

1. check from central admin > Upgrade and migration > Check product and patch installation status... make sure you KB2965261 is mentioned over here as installed.
2. you can also check from `control panel ? program and Features`, make sure correct Kb install.
3. Also Make sure that you ran the PSconfig wizard on all server in the farm.

Answer (score 0):

Running command `PSConfig.exe -cmd upgrade -inplace b2b` in PowerShell resolved the issue. The databases had not been upgraded yet.